# JQuery, strip all tags, wrap new ones and clone and append

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to clone the `p` elements in `.someClass`, remove the `p` tags while leaving the text, then wrap them with and `li` tags and finally put those into the `.anotherClass`'s `ul` tag?

For example:

```
    //untouched code like this
    <div class="someClass">
    <p>Some text1</p>
    <p>Some text2</p>
    <p>Some text3</p>
    </div>

    //jQuery cloned and apppended code must like this

    <div class="anotherClass">
    <ul>
    <li>Some text1</li>
    <li>Some text2</li>
    <li>Some text3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You really need to clarify what steps you want to have happen.

Comment: So are you asking how to clone the "p" elements in someClass, remove the "p" tags while leaving the text, then wrap them with and "li" tags and finally put those into the "anotherClass"'s ul tag?

Comment: Absolutly yes. Sorry for my English and newby in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would not use classes to identify in this case. I would use an id since you could have more than one "someClass" and more than one "anotherClass", but since I don't know what else you are doing I will answer with the assumption that there is only one of each:

```
var some_class_div = $(".someClass");
var another_class_ul = $(".anotherClass").find("ul");

some_class_div.find("p").each(function()
{
    another_class_ul.append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
});
```

Might I also recommend that you give the ul an id. Then you can use $("#ul_id"); instead of $(".anotherClass").find("ul");